# Can i receive usdc to my coinbase wallet via email address

Tags: wallets, coinbase, usdc, receive

I work at a company that has usdc voia coinbase payment method, and it only asks for the email, given thay, coinbase.com doesn't support my country and only coinbase wallet is available, so i provided my coinbase wallet email in the payment field, my question is, is that okay? Will i receive my payment to my wallet! Because they say you don't need coinbase.com account to use coinbase wallet. I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: No idea. You could just try sending a minimal amount to see what happens.